# Dissolving polygons that intersects in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, overlapping-features, dissolve

I want to gather all the polygons in my shapefile that intersects with each other in several groups. If they had shared a common field I would have used the "Dissolve" tool but they don't share any common field.

Is there an easy way to dissolve by location or something similar?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can dissolve without a dissolve field but Im not sure if that is what you want.

I suspect it is:

1. [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve)
2. [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts)
3. Field calculate [`@row_number`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#variables)
4. [Intersect](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection) output with your original data. Now you have your input data with a group attribute:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

First you run [`Dissolve`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve), then you use [`Multi to singleparts`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) to separate your blobs from each other. This removes individual attributes, but if you have those, you could run `Dissolve` using any of these attributes.

Alternatively you could add cluster IDs to your circles using the [DBSCAN clustering](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#dbscan-clustering).